# Authentication - key in each ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, authentication

Im writing new app and this time i want to completely separate HTML/JS layer from the PHP layer. Thats because I'll do phonegap version in the future.

I have question about authentication. This time I can't use session variables so i must figure out new way of authentication. Im going to try it this way:

1. User fills login form and send it via ajax to php file.
2. Php file checks whether login and password are ok or not, and then create a key-token for that user. Save it on his side (ex. in mysql) and return it to the client side as javascript.
3. Browser is receiving key-token and save it in session_storage.
4. Each ajax request is attached by this token and then verified by php.

Is there a hole in that plan?. Maybe there is much easier/better solution. Its inspired by how php session works but with key-token instead of session id. Please help me.

Comment: Well, the way you are doing it should be good enough. You can even encrypt the token and validate the token on each request against the parameters you define like external ip, temporary session id stored on the database, and others.

Comment: You reinvented session management. "but with key-token instead of session id" --- what is the difference between "key-token" and session id? Why cannot you treat "session id" as a token?

Comment: This is the basis of OAuth2. Would be worth your while to look into implementing an OAuth2 solution on your back-end so that you can do the web-app, phonegap, or even present your own API.

Answer (score 2):

> I can't use session variables

What you describe sounds *exactly* like a session, but you're going to implement itself yourself rather than using the known, tested properties and flexibility of the standard PHP session handler. Hence even if you avoid the inherent design pitfalls, you run the risk of injecting defects in your implementation.

I would strongly urge you to use the standard PHP mechanism (although you might want to consider a more complex save handler, even if it's just enabling the multi-layer function).

Given that what you describe is no different from the PHP handler, then, yes it will work if implemented correctly - is it secure? Not from the information you've provided.

Session storage does offer the possibility of carrying out more secure operations without resorting to SSL (although HTTPS is a *must have* if security is important) since you can pre-share encryption keys (but the initial key negotiation is highly vulnerable).

OTOH what you describe is vulnerable to sniffing, injection and CSRF.

Comment: I would love to use standart php mechanism, but as far as I know it doesnt work with crossdomain ajax. Am i right?

Comment: Again, there's nothing in your question to show how your approach is any different from a PHP session with regard to cross-domain Ajax.

Comment: Maybe you could update your question to show how how the cross domain authentication works with your model.